# How to write server side Java function for OrientDB

Tags: java, stored-procedures, server-side, orientdb

I want to write server side Java function, similar to DB stored procedure. I modified the code snippet from OrientDB latest user guide [custom functions](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Functions.html) to make the code could compile. After registration, call this function always report error:

> No function with name 'bigger'

Then I checked the OrientDB technical support, he just suggested I wrote plugin. But It is not good choice for my case.

BTW, Orientdb version is Community-2.2.7-GA, Java version is 1.8.0_92

```
package com.isc.enabler.topology.graph.dao.function;

    import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandContext;
    import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.OIdentifiable;
    import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.functions.math.OSQLFunctionMathAbstract;

    public class OSQLFunctionBigger extends OSQLFunctionMathAbstract {

        public static final String NAME = "bigger";

        public OSQLFunctionBigger() {
            super(NAME, 2, 2);
        }

        public String getSyntax() {
            return "bigger(<first>, <second>)";
        }

        public boolean aggregateResults() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object execute(Object iThis, OIdentifiable iCurrentRecord, Object iCurrentResult,
                Object[] iParameters, OCommandContext iContext) {
            if (iParameters[0] == null || iParameters[1] == null)
                // CHECK BOTH EXPECTED PARAMETERS
                return null;

            if (!(iParameters[0] instanceof Number)
                    || !(iParameters[1] instanceof Number))
                // EXCLUDE IT FROM THE RESULT SET
                return null;

            // USE DOUBLE TO AVOID LOSS OF PRECISION
            final double v1 = ((Number) iParameters[0]).doubleValue();
            final double v2 = ((Number) iParameters[1]).doubleValue();

            return Math.max(v1, v2);
        }
    }
```

Following my function registration and call code:

```
@Test
        public void testBiggerFunc() {
            OSQLFunctionBigger biggerFunc = new OSQLFunctionBigger();
            OSQLEngine.getInstance().registerFunction("bigger", biggerFunc);

            // registerGraphFunctions();

            String query = "SELECT name FROM OTopologyIotNode WHERE bigger(name.length(), 10) > 20";
            Iterable<Vertex> resultSet = this.graphDataAccessBridge
                    .executeQuery(query);
            for (Vertex vertex : resultSet) {
                String name = vertex.getProperty("name");
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you post the function? Thx in advance

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I uploaded the code:)

Comment: Finally, I wrote plugin to provide this server side function due to tight schedule. I will try JavaScript to write this function later, it can be registered on demand.